# node.js read protected files without running as root

Tags: linux, node.js, security

I'd like to read/write files using nodejs that live in a protected directory (/etc/apache2/sites-available). I understand that I can run the script with sudo but the idea of that makes me worried. Is there some way I can have node try to elevate for certain functions/calls without having the whole script run with root access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not provide elevated rights to your script, the script will be unable to mysteriously obtain those rights out of the thin air.

Granted you still need to modify the files, then consider giving write permissinos to your app.

---

If you are running app as user `joe`, and owner of `sites-available` files is `root`, then do: `chown -R joe:joe sites-available`.

But if some other user already uses those files, then you might get into permissions conflict. In this case, you can workaround using shared group, or SSH as that user.

Shortly, there are several ways of achieving your goal. But it is completely unrelated to *Node.js* technology, and all about *linux*, [*chown*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) and [*chmod*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).

Comment: Thank you! I'm still fairly new to linux. I'll use this advise as a kicking off point to do some more research.